# How to stop AppHelper.runConsoleEventLoop

Tags: python, macos, pyobjc

I have the following code:

```
import signal
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print("signal_handler")
    AppHelper.stopEventLoop()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, signal_handler)

try:
    print ('Hi!')
    AppHelper.runConsoleEventLoop(installInterrupt=True)
    print ('Bye!')
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print ('Exit event loop!')
    AppHelper.stopEventLoop()
```

I want to exit using Ctrl-C but is not working. I'm using python 2.7.10 over OSX.
Does anyone know how I can stop the runConsoleEventLoop?

Thanks

Comment: With `python3.9` it works. There is no need to use `signal`.

Just run your script and press `Ctrl-C`.